# broadcasting bitcoin transaction issue using bitcore-explorers

Tags: bitcore, javascript, nodejs

I have been trying to do a transaction using bitcore-lib. I have successfully created transaction object.

```
let bitcore_transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()
        .from(utxos[0])
        .to(to, +amnt)
        .fee(+gas)
        .change(from)
        .sign(pk);
```

I was trying to broadcast it using bitcore-explorers but it is giving me ssl handshake error. Is there any other alternate do do so?

Thank you

Comment: Which "bitcore explorers"? Did you build your own? If its from this repo, it looks pretty old: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers

Comment: I am using "bitcore-explorers" package. Please suggest some other alternate @pinhead. I want to make transaction for litecoin, bitcoin, eth and usdt

Comment: I don't know about those other coins but you could try out bcoin, it is actively maintained and supported. https://bcoin.io